# ApacheのPATH環境変数にパスを追加するには

Tags: apache, .htaccess

お世話になります。
ApacheのPATH環境変数にパスを追加したいのですが、.htaccessではできないのでしょうか。

[Apacheの環境変数PATHの変更方法](http://sierra-kilo.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/08/11/233708)

を参考に.htaccessに下記のように記述したのですが、うまくいかないようです。

```
SetEnv PATH /home/example/test:${PATH}
```

どこか書き方が間違っているのか、そもそも.htaccessではできないのか、ご存知でしたら教えていただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess`ではなく、Apacheの設定ファイル `httpd.conf`に`SetEnv`の記述をしてみてください。

参考にされたサイトでも、まず設定ファイルについての説明があって、その後`.htaccess`に記述した場合は「ファイルが存在するディレクトリ以下のPATHを変更」とあります。

念のため、何かしら設定の変更を行った場合にはhttpdプロセスの再起動(または設定ファイルの再読込み)も行っておきましょう。

Comment: お世話になります。そうですか。httpd.confを変更しないといけなかったんですね。とりあえず、今回利用しようとしているサーバーはその辺の設定を変更できないので、あきらめることにします。ありがとうございました。